# Passing stringstream values through a function, C++

Tags: c++, function, stringstream

I currently have a logging system that takes a char* and var args and then uses them to do a printf. This works well with C-style strings, but I'd something that's a little cleaner. Currently if I use std::stringstream I must create the stringstream outside of the logging system, and then use the char* to the string given by the stringstream. It looks something like this:

```
std::stringstream strStream;
strStream << "The value of x is: " << x;
logging::print( strStream.str().c_str() );
```

What I would like is to pass the paramaters into the function as if I was using them directly with a stringstream. Which would look something like this from the user's point of view:

```
logging::printStream("The value of x is: " << x);
```

or possibly like this:

```
logging::printStream("The value of x is: ", x);
```

Is there any way to use logging in such a way that I can use a stringstream without having to create it outside of the logging system's functions?

This is especially important because I intend to create a macro that prevents any of the function parameters from compiling in shipping builds. The macro will be useless if I have to create the stringstream outside of it and pass it in. Technically I could make a macro that does the stringstream stuff I'm talking about in this question, but that's pretty messy as I won't always be using stringstreams with this logging, so I would have a macro for the standard logging, and a different macro for using stringstreams that within it calls the macro for standard logging.

Comment: You could use variadic templates(instead of var args), and `std::cout` instead of printf. That way you wouldn't modify your extern code at all.

Comment: Log4cxx solves this elegantly, can you just use log4cxx?

Comment: @mfontanini: I will have to look into that. I'm not well-versed in variadic templates.
DougT.: I'm not familiar with Log4cxx, but I already have a logging system in place, I'm not sure if I'd want to replace the entire thing just for this bit of functionality I'm looking for.

Comment: Why don't you write a class streamLogging with a static method streamLogging::print that does what you want?

Comment: @JohnB: I'm curious how a static class would allow me to do this. I'll still need to be able to pass a stream of variables through a function. Could you provide a small example of code?

Comment: If you use C++11, you could define a string literal, and then just say something like `"some string as sstream"_ss << x` to convert the first to a stringstream and then just add onto it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with two HACK solutions, but they should work. The first doesn't use the scope resolution operator and is safer. The second uses a noop int variable to fake out the scoping.

```
#define logging_printStream(token) { std::stringstream o; o << token; logging::print(o.str().c_str()); }

namespace logging { int noop; }
#define printStream(token) noop = 0; { std::stringstream o; o << token; logging::print(o.str().c_str()); }

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    int i = 1;

    // MORE SAFE
    logging_printStream(i)
    logging_printStream("is this magic? " << (i ? "yes" : "no"))

    // LESS SAFE
    logging::printStream(i)
    logging::printStream("is this magic? " << (i ? "yes" : "no"))
}
```

---

I updated logging__printStream to logging_printStream because of 17.6.4.3.2

> 17.6.4.3.2 Global names [global.names]
>
> Certain sets of names and function signatures are always reserved to the implementation:
>
> - **Each name that contains a double underscore _ _** or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (2.12) is reserved to the implementation for any use.
> - Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the global namespace.

I left the declaration of main alone because of 3.6.1

> 3.6.1 Main function [basic.start.main]
>
> A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program. It is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main function. An implementation shall not predefine the main function. This function shall not be overloaded. **It shall have a return type of type int, but otherwise its type is implementation-defined.**

Comment: I've ended up going with a solution similar to this, despite not wanting to have to use macros. I did define my shipping version of the macro to compile to ((void)0) so that the parameters do not compile into the code.

Comment: -0.5 + -0.5: Your main function is non-conforming and double-underscores are reserved to the language implementation.

Comment: But main has a char*[] as the second argument, not a const char*[]

Comment: @phresnel The standard explicitly states that main is implementation-defined. I've yet had a compiler fail on `const char** argv`. I know that `const char**` is not the same as `char const* const* const`. Personally, I think `char const* const* const argv` looks confusing, so I don't use it in samples. `const char** argv` gets the point across that argv is not to be messed with.

Comment: @JefferyThomas: While I am all for const-correctness, do not forget that `main()` is a very special function. I propose to use one of the two forms that are guaranteed to be available, `int main()` or `int main (int argc, char *argv[])`. These are the canonical forms that every C++ programmer knows, and the forms that are guaranteed to be available by the standard. All other forms are indeed implementation defined.

Comment: @JefferyThomas: Just read the point about "confusion", let me add to my comment: I think more programmers will be confused by a non-guaranteed and unusual form of main() than by const pointers to const arrays.

Answer (score 1):

The following works as intended (tested -- replace output to cerr with your logging::print):

```
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>

class StringstreamLogger {
private:
    std::stringstream s;

public:
    StringstreamLogger () : s (std::ios_base::out) {
    }

    ~StringstreamLogger () {
    std::cerr << s.str () << std::endl; // logging::print (s.str ().c_str ());
    }

    std::stringstream& out () {
    return s;
    }
};

int main () {
    StringstreamLogger ().out () << "My log message";
    std::cerr << "Some later output to test for prompt logging (to ensure that logging is not delayed until the end of a block)" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you try multiple parameters?
`StringstreamLogger().out() << "My log message, and a number: " << someFcnThatReturnsFive();`

Does it work with a macro so that you do not evaluated anything after the initial <<?

Comment: The answer to your first question: Yes. It is not clear to me what you mean by the second question.

Comment: For example, if I use a macro such as `#define Log(x) MyLogger(x)`, this would allow me to then, in a release build use this macro instead: `#define Log(x) ((void)0)`, which would then mean that whatever 'x' is would get compiled out and have no run-time impact. I could probably make a macro with what you have, where 'x' becomes what is passed to StringstreamLogger().out()

Answer (score 0):

You can write this:

```
print(static_cast<std::ostringstream&>(std::ostringstream() << "The value of x is: " << x).str().c_str());
```

Maybe that's more to your liking?

Comment: That satisfies the requirement of having everything inside the function parameters, but that's a lot for someone to type every time they want to log something.

Comment: @NicFoster: Absolutely :-) But you could take this as an inspiration for your own custom class that offers a similar interface.

Comment: I think this is the whole point of user-defined string literals to be honest. You get the conversion, but it's a lot shorter to write, and you still specify you want that conversion.

Comment: I currently cannot make use of C++11, unfortunately. Trust me, I'd love to.

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, you could ...

```
class Something {
public:
    std::ostream& error() const { ... code to return some std::ostream ... }
};

...

int main () {
    Something something;
    something.error() << "Frobnicate" << 4;
}
```

Later you could add your own proxy-object with overloaded stream operators (which I think is still easier than writing your own stream derived from `std::ostream`).

Of course there's already tons of logging frameworks out there, look into them at first.

Comment: This would return a stream, but it wouldn't output it, or write it to my logging file. Something like this would work for me if I could take everything created by it and pass it to my method, inlined somehow.

Comment: @NicFoster: It is an answer to your question "Is there any way to use logging in such a way that I can use a stringstream without having to create it outside of the logging system's functions?". With my solution, you wouldn't have to create a stringstream outside of your logging system, but is flexible enough that you could.

Comment: It's a partial answer, I not only wanted something to create the stream for me, but I wanted a method I could pass the parameters into, and I wanted it to work with a macro that I could use so that the parameters would not be evaluated in some cases, like a shipping build.

Answer (score 0):

How about a custom type that overloads the output streaming operator?

```
struct logger
{
    std::stringstream ss_;

    template <typename T>
    friend logger& operator << (logger& l, T const& t) 
    {
    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
        l.ss_ << t;
    #endif

        return l;
    }

    ~logger()
    {
    #ifdef DEBUG_MODE
        // output ss_.str().c_str() to your logger.
    #endif
    }
};
```

And then whenever you need to log output just

```
logger log;
log << "Log this stuff: " << x << '\n';
```